# WebView Navigating event is working for .aspx page but not working for ashx page Xamarin Forms

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have created a Single Sign On Integration For Mobile App using Webview in Xamarin Forms.
I have initialized my webview Source as

```
webview.Source="https://dev-146240.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id=0oaecgo3lfDfsW5YX0h7&redirect_uri=https://192.168.1.15/workingN/SERVICES/SSOHandler.ashx&response_type=code&scope=openid&login_hint=ankur.gupta@kanrad.com&state=OFFLINE_ankur.gupta@kanrad.com";
```

Here I have given redirect_uri on which the page gets navigated after the successfull authentication from the third party.So,in my redirect_uri web page i am redirecting the page to  some (blank.html?JWTTOken) with JWT token as query string.
Now i have created webview Navigating event to check whether the navigation is taking place in my webView.When i debug the webview Navigating event then it is working till the redirect_uri page is called and not working when it is getting redirected from the redirect_uri page.
Please help me in finding the solution.